# If $(x+y-3)^2 + (x-y-7)^4 = 0$, then find $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I can't solve this problem. Someone please help! (I need Real Solution)

Comment: Are you taking about reals because there might be many complex solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**

Because squares of real numbers are non-negative, we have $x+y-3=x-y-7=0$.